# poner un link en un botón

Tags: html, html5

he estado tratando de colocar un link dentro de un botón que tengo con onclick="location.href='link'" pero al momento de colocar el link al final en la parte del "//" se me comenta el código y no funciona, he visto en muchos ejemplos que lo hacen así.

les dejo mi codigo a continuacion:

```
<button type="submit" class="linea" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:5500/Eventos'"><img src="imagenes/iconoPDF.jpg"></button>
```

tambien provado poniendo el boton dentro de un form pero de esta manera no logro alinear los botones uno en lado del otro y quedan hacia abajo

les dejo ese codigo tambien:

```
  <form action="http://localhost:5500/Eventos">
  <button type="submit" class="linea"><img src="imagenes/iconoPDF.jpg"></button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es redireccionar, es mejor la etiqueta  html
Ejemplo:

```
<a href="milugar">Ir a un lugar</a>
```

Esta seria la forma correcta de usar una redireccion, le puedes poner las clases y estios que desees para que se asemeje a un boton o podrias poner el boton dentro de la etiqueta a incluso de la siguiente forma :

```
<a href="milugar"><button>Ir a algun lugar</button></a>
```

Pero lo considero innecesario, pudiendo hacerlo solamente con la etiqueta

Te dejo mas informacion al respecto en el siguiente enlace: [Etiqueta a html](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: hola, tengo un problema disculpa, me funciono bien lo que me recomendaste pero quiero colocar texto debajo del botón y al hacerlo vuelven a quedar uno debajo del otro como antes, probé colocándole el display:inline-block pero nada

Comment: Lo solucione al final lo puse todo dentro de un table y le di un width de toda la pagina para que se adapte dependiendo del tamaño de la pagina

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está bien. El problema es el enlace al que quieres redireccionar.
Si esa dirección esta dentro de tu proyecto, copia la ruta de este y no el enlace del puerto donde lo estas ejecutando; Ejemplo:

usa este

```
<button type="submit" class="linea" onclick="location.href='Mi-proyecto/Eventos'"><img src="imagenes/iconoPDF.jpg"></button>
```

en lugar de este

```
<button type="submit" class="linea" onclick="location.href='http://localhost:5500/Eventos'"><img src="imagenes/iconoPDF.jpg"></button>
```